# Create role in Sybase with offline database

Tags: sybase, offline, sap-ase, role

How to create a role in Sybase which has one of the db as offline. It gives 950 error. Funny part is, it creates the role in the database but the message says

> Please wait and try your command again later.
>   Sybase error code=950
>   Severity Level=14, State=1, Transaction State=0

Comment: Your question does not makes sense.  You said it gives an error, but creates the role.  How are you determining that it creates the role?  What isn't working after the role creation.  Typically the database has to be online for the role to be created, since it needs to write to system tables within the target database.

Comment: Exactly @MichaelGardner. It should not create a role. I believe this is a bug. If you try creating a new role when database is offline directly using Sybase Central than it throws an error saying that one of the database is offline. You accept it and than click on Finish it will show that this role already exist.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing may be related to how ASE packages the transactions, and not really a bug.

The role itself is created in the master database (master..sysserverroles & master..sysloginroles), then the role is added to the user database (myUserDB..sysroles).  This is likely created in multiple transactions, so the transaction to create the role itself is successfully completing, but the transaction to add the role to the database is failing, since the database is offline.

So the tool is telling you the truth, that the role exists, but it still needs to be added to the user database, once the database is back online.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but this behavior is not just when try from Sybase Central but also when we try from our code and Interactive SQL too. I am a newbie to this but if my understanding is right when we try creating role from procedure than we can say that there are multiple transactions and some part of the procedure that rollbacks the previous instructions is not working, but we are using **create role** command and this should either create a role and throw a warning or should not create a role at all.

Comment: @KshitishSC Interesting..but it still seems that regardless of the tool, the role creation and the database assignment is treated as separate transactions.